# Passing Sql results to variables

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

This is my 1st attempt at an sql query. My query below works well, but how do I get the results into VBA variables so I can use them?

```
    Dim mSQL As String = "select AD_ADDR1, AD_ADDR2, PR_SALEPR1, SC_SOURCE1, SC_SOURCE2, FN_CONC1,FN_CONC2, DT_SALTIM1, LC_LOCAT1, RG_RIGHTS, ST_SITSIZE, ST_SITEVW,DA_DESAPL1, DA_CONSTQL, AG_AGYRBLT, AG_COND1, RM_TOTAL, RM_BED,RM_BATH, SF_GLA, BM_BSM1, BM_BSM2, FU_FUNCTUT, HC_HTCOOL, EE_EFFIC1,CR_GARPRK1, PF_PORPAT1, BL_BLANK1, BL_BLANK2, BL_BLANK3, HS_PRIOR1, HS_PRIOR2, HS_PRIOR3, HS_DSDATE from TOTALFormSource"
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Try
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
                con.Open()
                Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    dt = ds.Tables(0)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: Your title and tags have VBA but your code is VB.NET  - they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This may give you an idea. It probably doesn't compile (I'm installing software now so can't use VS):

```
Dim mSQL As String = "select AD_ADDR1, AD_ADDR2, PR_SALEPR1, SC_SOURCE1, SC_SOURCE2, FN_CONC1,FN_CONC2, DT_SALTIM1, LC_LOCAT1, RG_RIGHTS, ST_SITSIZE, ST_SITEVW,DA_DESAPL1, DA_CONSTQL, AG_AGYRBLT, AG_COND1, RM_TOTAL, RM_BED,RM_BATH, SF_GLA, BM_BSM1, BM_BSM2, FU_FUNCTUT, HC_HTCOOL, EE_EFFIC1,CR_GARPRK1, PF_PORPAT1, BL_BLANK1, BL_BLANK2, BL_BLANK3, HS_PRIOR1, HS_PRIOR2, HS_PRIOR3, HS_DSDATE from TOTALFormSource"
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet

Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
        con.Open()
        Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(ds)
            dt = ds.Tables(0)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    ' You can now access dr("AD_ADDR1"), etc.
Next
```

Note that I got rid of the `= Nothing`. You don't need it. You also didn't show us what was in your `Catch`, so I got rid of the `Try`.